# Include libprotobuf.a in Android CMake file

Tags: android, c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Protocol Buffers in C++ under Android (x86, x86_64, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a). Using [these build scripts](https://github.com/Dimon4eg/protobuf-android), I have been able to generate `libprotobuf.a` static libraries for the different architectures.

However, I am struggling to make the connection between the static libraries and the `test_spec.pb.cc` and `test_spec.pb.h` files that I generated with my system's global protobuf compiler of the same version (3.19.2).

**What I have tried**

- I have tried setting both the `Protobuf_LIBRARY` and `Protobuf_LIBRARIES` to the path to `libprotobuf.a`
- I have tried setting `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR` to the `include` directory I generated running the `extract_includes.bat.in` script in protobuf's cmake folder
- I have tried finding protobuf using `find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )` and `find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED HINTS _path_to_dir_containing_lib_and_include_)`
- I have tried setting `Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER` to a directory containing libprotobuf.a and the include folder

This is my current CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/../cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(protobuf STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(protobuf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ../cpp/libs/${ANDROID_ARCH}/google/protobuf/libprotobuf.a)

INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
SET(Protobuf_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
SET(Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER ../cpp)
SET(Protobuf_LIBRARIES protobuf)
SET(Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR ../cpp/include/google/protobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
ADD_LIBRARY(cpp
            SHARED
            ../cpp/rn-etsi-parser.cpp
            cpp-adapter.cpp
)

# Specifies a path to native header files.
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
            ../cpp
)
```

And this is the current error I get when I run it:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (FIND_PACKAGE):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
of the following names:
  ProtobufConfig.cmake
  protobuf-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set      
"Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If       
"Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has  
been installed.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well written question! Notes: 1) if using `find_package`, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't `add_library(protobuf)`. 2) Use `list(APPEND)` to add to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Q: Where and how did you install protobuf? (please add that to your question description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/david-fong)'s nudge and various CMake/C++ tutorials I was able to figure out a solution that works for my use case.

**What I did:**

- I moved both `libprotobuf.a` as well as the respective `include` to a folder within my `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`
- I cleaned up my eclectic mix of `find_package`, `add_library`, and `find_protobuf`
- I added the linker flag `-llog` to bypass [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2719)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-llog")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH [
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
])

ADD_LIBRARY(protobuf STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(protobuf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/google/protobuf/${ANDROID_ABI}/libprotobuf.a)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/include/)

ADD_LIBRARY(cpp
            SHARED
            ../cpp/rn-etsi-parser.cpp
            cpp-adapter.cpp
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cpp PUBLIC protobuf)

# Specifies a path to native header files.
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
            ../cpp
)
```

I'd be interested to know, however, if there is a way to 'inject' prebuilt protobuf libraries into CMake's find_protobuf workflow, so that I could make use of features like `protobuf_generate_cpp`.